# Is there a command to print all the terminal processes run by a user?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I know that

```
# ps -u someUser
```

will print the terminal processes currently being run by a user. Is there a way to get all of the past terminal processes that user ever ran when you're logged in as the root user?

I want all the processes they ran like:

```
$ php update_financials.php
```

A command like:

```
cat ~someUser/.bash_history
```

would bring up commands I don't care about like

```
$ pwd

$ ls -l
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps user process accounting (as provided by the 'acct' package) might help.

Here's the URL for acct: http://www.gnu.org/software/acct/

The command you'd use is 'lastcomm' (last command).

Here's some blog entries that describe how process accounting can be used:

http://beginlinux.com/blog/2010/01/monitoring-user-activity-with-psacct-or-acct/

Comment: It will not record arguments alongside with the executives. i.e. some user at some time executed `rm` would tell you nothing on which file is deleted.